# Can Stack Overflow be a little more proactive in dissuading people from doing stupid things?

Tags: feature-request

I propose that every time SO encounters a new question with the words "html" and "regex" in the same sentence, a modal popup is displayed to the OP:

> ### Warning!
>
> It appears you are trying to do something incredibly stupid.
>
> Please choose how to proceed:
>
> - I'm dumb, post my question anyway
> - I'm not dumb, take me to the HTML Agility Pack web site

This is the general idea - obviously we may want to review the text before launching the feature.

*I'm not affiliated with HAP in any way, shape or form.*

Comment: That banner doesn't look very professional to me.

Comment: Why catch that and not obvious SQL injection? Obsolete / dangerous API functions? Undefined behavior?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: it's not meant to.  No site is going to call its users stupid.  This is just an example.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: sure!  but one thing at a time, eh? :)

Comment: D*** hippies with their free love, free drugs and politely worded popup messages!

Comment: @samgak: and lack of imagination and bag full of down votes, apparently.

Comment: That pop up seems profoundly unhelpful, unnecessarily aggressive language aside. It doesn't mention *what the dumb thing is*! It's also too broad, what if the user types *"I tried parsing the HTML with regex, but then..."*? And are we going to try to do this for every dumb thing people can do? What makes this dumb thing so special?

Comment: On the other hand, if you can produce something that can parse any question and reliably determine when the OP is trying to parse HTML with regular expressions, then I hope you have plenty of room in your trophy cabinet and bank account!

Comment: Hmm, a filter on the words "dumb" and "stupid" for meta questions jump to mind.  But you would have clicked the Submit button anyway so it is just wasted energy.

Comment: Insert PHP joke.

Comment: @jonrsharpe -- I'm sure someone could write a good regex to parse a page full of questions to accomplish that. * ducks *.

Comment: i feel like a pop-up should have appeared when you started writing this question with the text "hey buddy, public masturbation is a crime.  also, get over yourself."

Answer (score 11):

This would produce far too many false positives to be useful. Even the canonical [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1288) question, which spawned the famous ["The <center> cannot hold"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1288) answer (AKA, TONY THE PONY HE COMES) was not asking how to *parse* HTML with regex. The OP was simply asking how to match a few opening tags, which is perfectly doable with regex and not stupid at all. A lot of *actual people* didn't catch this subtle distinction. Writing a program that would understand the difference would probably not be worth the effort.

Comment: Of course there would be false positives.  Software can never be better than the person/people that write it, and as you pointed out, we're all flawed.  The point was `1` to provide instant feedback to the questioner.  In this day of the internet parsing HTML (properly) is a big deal.  And `2` to give the OP the ability to continue on in case of a false positive.  It's entirely possible to turn this into a very positive experience once the hippies get a hold of the language.

Comment: Instead of "It looks like you are trying to do something dumb", that could become "Based on our analysis of your question it appears you are trying to parse HTML with Regular Expressions.  If this is accurate you may want to try a library specifically designed for parsing HTML.  RegEx is a general pattern matching engine and not well-suited to this task." - If I were a hippie that cared whether people were offended by the free help I provided.

Comment: @SamAxe I didn't just say that there would be false positives, I said there would be *far too many* of them. We already have people commenting and answering "just use a parser" way too often when it's not appropriate. What you're suggesting is that we automatically do that 100% of the time. We need fewer of these knee-jerk reactions, not more of them.